# Azure IoT Edge node SDK invokeDeviceMethod not working asynchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I am trying to return a result for a direct method call in an async fashion.

I tried:

```
var client = Client.fromConnectionString(process.env.AZ_IOT_CONNECTION_STRING);
var methodParams = {
  methodName: "method",
  payload: 10, // Number of seconds.
  responseTimeoutInSeconds: 60
};

// Call the direct method on your device using the defined parameters.
client.invokeDeviceMethod(
  req.params.deviceId,
  methodParams,
  (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log("success");
    }
  }
);
```

On Device:

```
const method = async (request, response) => {
  const longProcess = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve();
      }, 5000);
    });
  };

  try {
    await longProcess();
    response.send(200, `success`);
  } catch (error) {
    response.send(500, `Error: ${error}:`);
  }
};


client.onDeviceMethod("method", method);
```

**Expected**: Returns success after 5 seconds

**Actual**: returns "BadRequest" "errorCode :400027" but the method is executed correctly.

Answer (score -1):

please work with the promise function instead of the callback like so:

```
async deviceSyncInvoke(deviceID: string, methodName: string, data:any, responseTimeoutInSeconds?: number): Promise<[number, any]> {
        try{
            if (!this.client){
                await this.openClient();
            }

            const methodParam: DeviceMethodParams = {
                methodName: methodName,
                payload: JSON.stringify(data)
            }

            // The minimum and maximum values for responseTimeoutInSeconds are 5 and 300 seconds.
            //If timeout is not provided, it the default value of 30 seconds is used
            if (responseTimeoutInSeconds && responseTimeoutInSeconds !== undefined) {
                methodParam.responseTimeoutInSeconds = responseTimeoutInSeconds;
            }


            const res: ResultWithIncomingMessage<any> = await this.client.invokeDeviceMethod(deviceID, methodParam);
            if (res.message.statusCode == undefined || res.message.statusCode > 299) {
                throw new Error(`statusCode: ` + res.message.statusCode + `statusMessage: ` + res.message.statusMessage);
            }

            return [2001, "message invoking command with res: " + res];
        }catch(err) {
            return [5000, "error deviceSyncInvoke: " + err];
        }
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question,  It depends on the version of the SDK version you're using. You're just picking apart things that don't matter.